# How to insert an Object as an Array element in javascripts

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to insert an object as an array element in javascripts. for ex:

```
var student1 = new Student();
student1.setStudentName("Charlie"); //set method

var student2 = new Student();
student2.setStudentName(10);
```

I also use getter method to return the values.But, in the following array

```
var studentsArray = new Array();
```

I need to pass `student1` and `student2` objects into `studentsArray` and display student names(Charlie and Eric).

Comment: have you tried solving this on your own?

Comment: can we get "javascripts" corrected to "javascript" in the title name?

Answer (score 1):

You can `push` it or just use the literal.

```
var studentsArray = [student1, student2];
// or studentArray.push(student1, student2);
```

Printing the names would be simple

```
studentsArray.forEach(function(student){
   alert(
          // display the appropriate property of student
        );
});
```

Comment: It might be worth showing how to use [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) correctly.

Comment: @DavidThomas ah! Thanks for the edit, forgot that.

Comment: Thanku,here I have used both the push() and literal notation.When I try to print those values using console                            Array [ Object, Object ] I am getting like this

Comment: Yes, because you're trying to print an Object, which calls `toString()` on the *whole object*; what you should (probably) do is print the properties of an object `console.log(student.name)` (presumably). And, Amit, no problem at all :)